# Able to answer a closed question from the webapp

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, closed-questions, mobile-web

When answering a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50902979/java-code-to-split-the-rowcount-obtained-from-database-into-percentage-parts/50903091) today from my mobile phone, I somehow could post my answer, although the question has been closed, while I wrote it.

The time when the question has been closed as off-topic:

[image: on hold message, with time]

Differs by 3 to 4 minutes from the time, when I've posted my answer:

[image: answer time]

In the browser, this behaviour is fought against, by disabling the `[Post Your Answer]`-button and by adding a message in the SO-header which indicates that answers can no longer be posted.

So this clearly seems like a Bug in the webapp to me.

Comment: You started composing the answer before the closure right?

Comment: Yes, it has been closed while I wrote my answer